# drf-yasg provides wrong paths to URIs

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi, drf-yasg

In my application I need to have multiple Swagger pages with grouped endpoints for multiple clients.

One of my clients (paths) supplies mobile app API, another supplies web client API. URL patterns are kept in 2 different `urls.py` accordingly.

I'm using [drf-yasg](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to generate schema for my API.

To generate `swagger` specification for those I'm initializing 2 separate `schema_views` for each `urls.py` file like this:

```
from api_mobile.urls import urlpatterns as mobile_patterns
from api_web.urls import urlpatterns as web_patterns

mobile_schema_view = get_schema_view(
openapi.Info(
    title="Mobile API",
    default_version='v3',
),
public=True,
permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
patterns=mobile_patterns,
)

web_schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="Web API",
        default_version='v1',
    ),
    public=True,
    permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
    patterns=web_patterns,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'api/mobile/docs',
        mobile_schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0),
        name='mobile-schema-ui'
    ),
    path(
        'api/web/docs',
        web_schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0),
        name='web-schema-ui'
    ),

    path('api/mobile/v3/', include('api_mobile.urls'), name='mobile_urls'),
    path('api/web/v1/', include('api_web.urls'), name='web_urls'),
    ...
]
```

Where `mobile_patterns` and `web_patterns` are just a list of url patterns.

If I open `http://localhost:8000/api/mobile/docs` or `http://localhost:8000/api/web/docs` I do see correctly generated schema for both lists of patterns, yet if I try to do a request directly from `swagger` specification page all endpoints return `404` error – they all try to do a request to non-existing url pattern without providing full path to endpoint.

So if I do a request to any view from `mobile` endpoints swagger tries to do a request at

`http://localhost:8000/some_mobile_url/` instead of `http://localhost:8000/api/mobile/v3/some_mobile_url/`

And situation is the same for another schema, swagger wrongly requests `http://localhost:8000/some_web_url/` instead of using full path 
`http://localhost:8000/api/web/v3/some_web_url/`

Obviously being able to test API directly through `swagger` is very important so specification itself is not enough in my case.

Is this an issue in me misconfiguring `swagger` itlesf or should I be somehow providing path to `swagger` so it prepends full path to each url accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working fine for us:

***api_schema.py***

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from drf_yasg.views import get_schema_view
from drf_yasg import openapi

from books.api.v1.urls import urlpatterns as api_v1


API_DESCRIPTION = openapi.Info(
    ...
)

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    info=...,
    ...
    url='https://oursite.company.io/',
    patterns=[
        url('api/v1/', include(api_v1)),
    ],
)
```

***books.api.v1.urls.py***

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^books', ...),
    ...
]
```

***urls.py***

```py
from ...api_schema import schema_view

...
url(r'^api/v1/', include(api_v1)),
url(r'^api/schema(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$',
        schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0),
        name='api_schema_v1'),
...
```

Comment: Do you register `schema_view` and `api_v1` patterns  in some kind of main pattern list containing routes to documentation page and to `api_v1` URIs? Because from your example I don't see how django knows where to show swagger page for given set of endpoints.

Comment: Also is there a way to get base url path for `url` field in `get_schema_view` directly from django configuration. What I mean is: let django itself provide base path.

Comment: @StanRedoute obtaining the url field from Django config seems better, agree :thumbs-up:

Comment: That said: what should you then pass as `url` parameter to `get_schema_view` to avoid hardcoded value?

Comment: @StanRedoute `url=f'{settings.PROTOCOL}://{settings.BACKEND_DOMAIN}:{settings.BACKEND_PORT}'`